# Pandas / matplotlib stacked horizontal percentage barchart

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

[image]

```
df_new.plot(

kind = 'barh',
x = 'Measure',
stacked = True,
title = 'Stacked Bar Graph',
mark_right = True)
```

This gives me a key error on Measure - can't figure out why?

Answer (score 1):

You need to tranpose your dataframe with [**`pandas.DataFrame.T`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html) to get one horizontal stacked bar:

Try this:

```
(
    df_new
      .T
      .plot(kind = 'barh',
            stacked = True,
            title = 'Stacked Bar Graph',
            mark_right = True)
)
```

##### # Output :

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. Could you explain why the index needs resetting (just for my learning). Also I'm trying to get all the ethnic groups on one bar e.g. stacked - the whole bar repenting 100% if that makes sense.

Comment: Transpose was what I needed for one bar.

Comment: All right, I updated my answer ;)